# Show div content upto two lines only

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have issue with showing some content in div.
I have some text consider 10 lines of content which I have to show in div.
I would like to design in such a way that initially div will show 2 lines of content only, & have one link "Read Complete". & when I will click on that link the whole content must be shown & link must be changed to "Hide". & if I again click on Hide link it must be again shown only 2 lines of content.

Please help with me this issue.

Update: When the content is of two line @ the end of content it must show 3 dots (...)

Comment: I have tried with div height increase decrease. But no luck.

Comment: Why no luck? doesn't it work?

Comment: No... Actually I want am not able to do exactly the way it should be.

Comment: -1 You have not included any code or displayed any indication that you have researched the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will help you

```
<div id="mydiv">
Please read the documentation.
For updates please follow our blog, tweets or become a fan.
    <span><a href="#" id="more" onclick="full_view(this.id)">more</a></span>
<span style="display:none;" id="disMore"><p>Please read the documentation.    
For updates please follow our blog, tweets or become a fan.Please read the documentation.
For updates please follow our blog, tweets or become a fan.Please read the documentation.
For updates please follow our blog, tweets or become a fan.</p></span>
<span><a href="#" id="hide" onclick="half_view(this.id)" style="display:none;">hide</a></span>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function full_view(e) {
document.getElementById('disMore').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('more').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('hide').style.display = "block";
}
function half_view(e) {
document.getElementById('disMore').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('more').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('hide').style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Actually I am using dynami8c content which comes from servlet in a String type.

Comment: please do mention in your question which is dynamic content

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
<div id="text">
   Your content...
</div>

<a href="#" id="readall">Read all</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
    //Change this variable to show more or less lines:
    var nrOfLines = 2;
    var height = 0;

    //Get line height
    height = $('div#text').css('line-height');
    height = height.substring(0, height.search('px'));
    height = (height * nrOfLines) + 'px';
    //Set div to only show 2 lines
    $('div#text').css({'height' : height});

    setTriggers();

    function setTriggers() {
        $('a#readall').click(function() {
           $(this).attr('id', 'hide');
            $(this).html('Hide');
            $('div#text').css({'height' : 'auto',
                               'overflow' : 'auto'});
            setTriggers();
        });

        $('a#hide').click(function() {
           $(this).attr('id', 'readall');
            $(this).html('Read all');
            $('div#text').css({'height' : height,
                               'overflow' : 'hidden'});
            setTriggers();
        });
    }

});
```

And your CSS:

```
div#text {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I made an example here:  http://jsfiddle.net/c5sza/2/

You could pimp it some more by using a sliding effect etc.

Comment: Aim of this platform is not to give you a chewed out fully functional solution (hire and pay for a developer for that), but to give you an idea on how to do it. This is a perfect answer to your question. Now it's up to you to enhance it to suit your needs.

Comment: I know dat buddy. But I am new 2 js n css stuff.

Comment: Then start learning and start using Google rather than downvoting people's answers who are 100% correct and helpful.

Comment: Hey buddy I havent down vote Ur answer. Its perfect answer 4 simple content. N Also why should I waste 1 point worth on down voting others?

Comment: @Yogee Here, I changed it to work no matter your font-size: http://jsfiddle.net/c5sza/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **PURE CSS line-clamp Property** to save your design. Please do have a look

```css
  

.card .card-header {
  font-weight: 600
}

.card .card-body .content {
  line-height: 20px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container my-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h4 class="mb-3">Line-Clamp Text-Ellipsis Example</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">BTC - Bitcoin</div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="content"> Bitcoin is the most secure and robust cryptocurrency in the world, currently finding its way across the world of business and finance. Bitcoin was thought of as Internet money in its early beginnings. Unlike fiat currencies Bitcoin is a decentralized
            currency. That means that a network of users control and verify transactions instead of a central authority like a bank or a government. Up to this day, Bitcoin uninterruptedly works as money one person pays another person for goods and services.
            Once Bitcoin is exchanged, the record of the transaction is publicly recorded onto a ledger known as the blockchain, which other Bitcoin users, known as miners, verify by putting those transactions into a block and adding it to the blockchain
            after Proof of Work (PoW).</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use CSS `line-height` and `height` to control that. here is my simple demo on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7xv6J/